# How to fetch data from link tag in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my models I have a class called "Add_prod",I have created few columns like book,author,price and so on.In the templates I have created two hyperlinks for sorting data in ascending/descending order of price."name" attribute is not supporting in anchor tag.I also tried with id attribute instead of name,but still no use.So how to fetch data from anchor tag so that I arrange products in sorted order.

Views.py,

```
def welcome_user(request):  
    if 'low_price' in request.GET:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all().order_by('price')
    elif 'high_price' in request.GET:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all().order_by('-price')
    else:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
    context = { "Products":my_products}

    #rest of code for other functionalities
    return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

My template file,

```
<form>
    <div style="text-align: right">
            <a name="low_price" href="{% url 'welcome_user' %}">Low Price</a>
            <a name="high_price" href="{% url 'welcome_user' %}">High Price</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to provide a parameter in your `url` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the URLs with the `query parameters` you are expecting in the view:

```
<a name="low_price" href="{% url 'welcome_user' %}?low_price">Low Price</a>
<a name="high_price" href="{% url 'welcome_user' %}?high_price">High Price</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without making any change to url?

Comment: You don't have to make any changes to the url pattern. That's why `?low_price` has been used as a query parameter so your url pattern remains same.

Comment: I think if I use drop down instead of hyperlink,then there will be no changes in the browser url also

Answer (score 1):

there are two way:

1 as @AKS answer.

2

```
def welcome_user(request,type):  
    if 'low_price' == type:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all().order_by('price')
    if 'high_price' == type:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all().order_by('-price')
    else:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
    context = { "Products":my_products}

    #rest of code for other functionalities


<form>
    <div style="text-align: right">
            <a name="low_price" href="{% url 'welcome_user' low_price %}">Low Price</a>
            <a name="high_price" href="{% url 'welcome_user' high_price%}">High Price</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

note in this way you actual visited .../welcome_user/low_price/ or .../welcome_user/hight_price/

so,you need to change `url patterns` to this
`url(r'^welcome_user/(?P<type>.+)/$','welcome_user')`

i like this way,since you do not need to look after any param. in another words you do not need to get or check anything from GET.if it is not illegal,it will not hit your view.

Comment: I am not sure this would work out of box. You would need to create new URL patterns for this.

Comment: yes,you do need to change url pattern,
url(r'^welcome_user/(?P<type>.+)/$','welcome_user')

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without making any change to url?

Comment: @Bhanukiran you must change `href` to add more information. when AKS and i say `url patterns` ,we mean `urls.py` in `django`. 
use AKS way , you do not need to change `view.py` and `urls.py`

Comment: I took his answer its working perfectly and thanks for you also

Answer (score 0):

@AKS advice did not work for me.

But the following did work:

```
<a href="{% link %}?param">Text</a>
```

And then in a view I specify:

```
if 'param' in request.GET:
    ...
```